# Firebase Authentication Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, aurelia

when i try development app based on firebase, i found this error or bug with newest firebase release, version 4.2.0. i try initialize app same on console page example, and try it:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("!!!!!!", "!!").catch(function(error){
        alert(error.message);
        console.log(error);
    });
```

i get it:
[image]

Comment: It's only with IE, or other browser also?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/122 (please indicate when cross-posting)

Comment: Only Internet Explorer;

Comment: i am certain it is something else in your code. You need to provide more context. I tested in IE11-win10: https://jsfiddle.net/dstsfxj6/ Substitute your api key and auth domain and your test email/password. It works for me.

Comment: yep, i get same error, and now i can think this is my browser, or unknow reason for it....